# gps en android es inconsistente con la ubicación actual

Tags: ionic

¿Cuánto se debe esperar para obtener la ubicación en android?, en este momento estoy utilizando un timeout de 7 segundos, estoy haciendo una app en ionic3, el error es que se dispara el timeout y nunca me encuentra la ubicación

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La precisión de un GPS Depende del número de satélites que tengas
>   disponibleS. Si apenas das tiempo a que coja unos pocos, la posición
>   es menos precisa. Debes aumentar el timeout y mirar la precisión de la medida que has obtenido. De ese modo, tú mismo serás capaz de parar la actualización en cuanto tengas una medida consistente con tus necesidades.

En el objeto `accuracy` deberías tener el valor de la precisión en un entero. 
La variable que debes mirar por tanto para saber si la medida es precisa, es esta: `position.coords.accuracy`

La documentación dice:

> **accuracy (number)**
>
> A double representing the accuracy of the latitude and longitude properties, expressed in meters.

La documentación [aquí](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/geolocation/)

> **EDIT:** te añado el código que creo que lo soluciona. No tengo Ionic aquí para probar, lo siento!!.

```
const subscription = this.geolocation.watchPosition().filter((p) => p.coords !== undefined).subscribe(position => {
 //Aquí compruebas si tu precisión está por debajo de los 50m
 if (position.coords.accuracy < 50)
 {
   console.log(position.coords.longitude + ' ' + position.coords.latitude);
   stopSubsciption()
 }
});

stopSubsciption()
{
  // To stop notifications
  subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```